# How to make a bootstrap alert box to appear below a button

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have created a page that contains a button that upon its click a bootstrap alert box is appeared either success or error according to certain events
The code is the following:

```
 <div class="col-lg-12">
   <button type="button" id="my_button" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg">Download</button>
     <span id="download_ok" class="alert alert-info">
         File downloaded successfully
     </span>
     <span id="download_fail" class="alert alert-danger">
               File failed to download
     </span>
</div>
```

While the jquery code is the following:

```
$('#download_ok').fadeIn({
  duration: 800
});

$('#download_fail').fadeIn({
 duration: 800
});
```

The code works correctly and the log message was printed right next to the button.
 When I tried to additional two buttons by making class into class="col-lg-4" the alert message was printed with incorrect format with the word "successfully" to overlap the words "File downloaded".I thought that it would be nice for the alert to appear on a new line right below the relevant button but whatever I tried with the CSS positioning or adding `<br/>` in html didn't get me to the needed outcome and the output format was always crashed.
Any ideas how to deal with this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change `span` to `div`

```
 <div class="col-lg-12">
   <button type="button" id="my_button" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg">Download</button>
     <div id="download_ok" class="alert alert-info">
         File downloaded successfully
     </div>
     <div id="download_fail" class="alert alert-danger">
               File failed to download
     </div>
</div>
```

Comment: With the addition of divs the alert is printed both on the right of the button and continues on the row below.

Comment: @ hunzaboy. Thanks a lot I must have missed a tag. It works fine

Answer (score 0):

**Firstly: Change the `span` to `div`**

```
<div class="col-lg-12">
    <button type="button" id="my_button" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg">Download</button>
    <div id="download_ok" class="alert alert-info">
        File downloaded successfully
    </div>
    <div id="download_fail" class="alert alert-danger">
        File failed to download
    </div>
</div>
```

**Secondly: You need to first hide the elements for them to fade in**

```
$('#download_ok').hide();
$('#download_fail').hide();

$('#download_ok').fadeIn({
    duration: 800
});

$('#download_fail').fadeIn({
    duration: 800
});
```